# Aeroglass and Visual Basic.Net

Tags: vb.net, window, border, aero, aero-glass

are there any tutorials, or, is there simple code to be used to control Aeroglass in VB.NET? I would like to know how to play with various effects and, if possible, how to do the Aeroglass effects done in Paint.NET 3.5. (The inside of the topbar is not straight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call the DWM API functions, which are described in [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163435.aspx), using P/Invoke.

For an example, see [here](http://my.opera.com/DFXBB/blog/2007/05/27/vb-net-vista-aero-glass-effect-window)

Comment: Thanks! How do I change black to another color, based on that tutorial?